# Implied types with a Pointer to Member template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, pointer-to-member

I'm working with pointer-to-member types inside templates, currently I have something like this going on:

```
template <typename Base, typename Type, Type Base::* Var>
struct Member
{
    //Stuff goes here.
};
```

But having to define Base, Type, and then Var, seems a little redundant, since Base and Type are implied in Var's type.

Is there some way to do this, such that, when using/calling the Member struct, it only needs to use the single pointer-to-member argument?  Like, in theory, something like this:

```
template <typename Base, typename Type, Type Base::* Var>
struct Member<Var>
{
    //stuff goes here
};

struct S
{
    int memberVal;
};

int main()
{
    Member<&S::memberVal> example;
};
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way. Only your first variant is correct. You are giving example where the C++ cyntax is not that elegant. Bit it is as it is.

Your second example has syntax of a template specialization. While it is definition of a new template. Most likely this will be put as an objection.

Comment: Theoretically, would it be something that could be added to the C++ standards, or is there some logical flaw or fallacy which would prevent this, in theory, as a whole?

Comment: I do not see flaws in what you are proposing. On the other hand templates are already OVERCOMPLICATED. There is little chance that this would be considered. Presonally I do not see `significant` gain in adding this feature. By the way, everybody can propose a change. C++ committee is very democratic.

Comment: True; however, as insignificant as it is, in the rare cases that it might come up, it could save a whole lot of boilerplate code.   I suppose that the suggestion, as a whole, would be to have implied-type constants in template parameter lists...   this is the 2nd "C++ inelegance" issue I've come upon in 2 days... yesterday, it was the lack of pointer-to-member-members issue.

Comment: @Serge: There is a basic issue here: type deduction is never applied to the template arguments. The template argument you want to pass in is a non-type argument, and for those the type must be provided in the template definition.

Comment: I heard stories that a lot of additions were rejected simply because they will be used `not enough often`. Committee agrees that the proposed feature  is useful, but, well, the C++ book is already thick. Think about developer who will read your code years later. What is the chance that he will know something that is written only on the page 836 of the doc?

Comment: @KirillKobelev well, hopefully, if he's reading code that I wrote, despite how unlikely it is that I would be more knowledgeable than someone else, he would have the sense to take anything unknown, and research or ask questions about it!  Spreading the knowledge to one more person!

Comment: I would not agree. Compactness of the language has value. This was one of the reasons of success of C. Programmers should work on their assignments and not to start investigation on any other piece of code. Plus remember that support engineers are often much less qualified than the people who write new code...

Comment: @Serge: Many people before you have been programming and managed to get along with the tools they had. I myself consider that C++ has some shortcomings, but given the alternatives, it is still my language of choice. In this (and your last question I remember) the problem is that you are expecting the language to offer the lower level details with the simplicity of a high level language, and that just cannot be done. You can choose to have higher level type of syntax at the cost of some efficiency (still much better than many other alternatives) or else have low level control with more pain.

Comment: @David, do not take it too hard. Serge invented an idea and asked a question. There is nothing wrong in that.

Comment: @KirillKobelev: No, I don't take that question or lack of answer bad. as a matter of fact I fought the same issue before, and I know really smart people that have tried once and again to get that to work before realizing that there is a core issue. The comment is more related to the comments in his previous question (pointer to member of a member). Well, that and that I don't quite understand people blaming the tool for the trade. This is a trade, and you have to get along with the tools that you have. If something is not possible, look for alternatives, rather than complaining about the tool

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Sorry, sorry!  I'm not trying to complain about the tool, although I guess it happened anyways; C++ will STILL be my language of choice, trust me.  It is much better than the alternatives, in my opinion!

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for cannot be achieved in C++ directly. The limitation is that for non-type template arguments, the type must be provided in the template definition. Type deduction is only applied to function arguments.

Depending on your real use case, there are alternatives that can be done, but they imply moving the member pointer from being a template argument (compile time) to a function argument (runtime). That is, given a type:

```
template <typename C, typename M>
struct Member {
   M C::*ptr;
   Member( M C::*ptr ) : ptr(ptr) {}
};
```

It is possible to create instances of it with the syntax:

```
auto x = create_member( &S::memberVal );
```

By using a few metaprogramming tricks, not too complex though:

```
template <typename T> struct MemberType;
template <typename T, typename M> 
struct MemberType<M T::*> {
   typedef Member<T,M> type;
};
template <typename T>
typename MemberType<T>::type
create_member( T mbrptr ) {
    typename MemberType::type r(mbrptr);
    return r;
}
```

But as I already mentioned, that means transforming the compile time argument into a runtime argument, and thus potentially inhibiting some of the optimizations that the compiler would do (namely inlining).

Comment: Ah, metaprogramming.  Perhaps one of my favorite things about C++ these days!